# Windows server 2008 R2 print server - printbrm not working

Tags: windows-server-2008, print-server

I am attempting to migrate a Windows 2008 R2 print server (queues, drivers et. al.) using printbrm. However, logged in as a domain admin, when trying to export, I keep getting the most frustrating and generic error from printbrm. Using the GUI or the Command Line, either with elevated privilege.

```
Log Name:      Application  
Source:        Microsoft-Windows-PrintBRM  
Date:          5/8/2012 10:18:52 AM  
Event ID:      57  
Task Category: (7)  
Level:         Error 
Keywords:      Classic  
User:          N/A  
Computer:      PRINT SERVER  
Description:  
Printbrm.exe (the Printer Migration Wizard or the command-line tool) failed to place a file in cabinet (CAB) file FILE.printerExport while backing up print queues. Error reported: 0x80004005. Unspecified error
. This can occur if the user does not have permission to create a file in the destination location, or if there is insufficient disk space or system resources.
```

Comment: Try running it from an elevated command prompt.

Comment: already done this, same error message

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<strike>Run the GUI as an administrator?  I know that many times, even logging in as an admin won't cut it for windows.  Right-click the GUI file/exe and select 'run as administrator.'  Give password, and try from there.</strike>

edit:  ok.  here.
`What is the size of the \windows\system32\spool\drivers directory on the machine you are backing up?  If it's near 2gig you are hitting the max file size for cab formatted files`

[Source](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/winserverprint/thread/0a827fe3-036e-4e3e-a55b-56099cf8384d) i found.  looks like a very simlar problem, and an answer.  good luck.

Comment: just tried this, same error message

Comment: ok, editing answer w/ more info.

Comment: now this sounds interesting - working....  Yup, my drivers directory is 2.9GB. Sounds like I need to work it down and try again.

Comment: following the directions on the link, cleaning out \windows\system32\spool\drivers and deleting unused drivers with the print management tool, I pushed the size down to 1.8GB and prinbrm worked. Thanks!! –

Comment: glad i could help!

Answer (score 0):

An update that improves the performance of the Printbrm.exe command-line tool in Windows 7 or in Windows Server 2008 R2 is available

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2752259